# Button Click Event Fire Only Second Click

Tags: asp.net, aspbutton

In ASP.NET My button click event doesn`t work on first click. But it works on the second click only.
I hope u can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to post some code for us to be able to help you. One thought is that you may be re-binding your data, and invalidating your first request. Did you miss an `if(!IsPostBack) { ... }`

If that's not it, you do need to show us

1. The code that assigns the event to a listener
2. Any code that binds the button
3. Any ASPX controls that contain the button (if it's in, say, a repeater)